# Google Sheets Copy value in Sets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am not sure the best way to ask this so I will give an example of what I am trying to do.

I have one tab in google sheets with several rows like so:
option 1
option 2
option 3

In a second sheet I want to create a formula that I can copy down that will produce something like this

prefix1_option1 
prefix2_option1 
prefix3_option1 
prefix1_option2 
prefix2_option2 
prefix3_option2 
prefix1_option3 
prefix2_option3 
prefix3_option3

Using formula like 
"prefix1_"&'Sheet'!A1 
"prefix2_"&'Sheet'!A1 
"prefix3_"&'Sheet'!A1 
works for the first one but does not copy properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(rept(concatenate({"prefix1_";"prefix2_";"prefix3_"}&char(9)),3),char(9)))&transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Sheet1!A:A&char(9),3)),char(9))) )
```

or alternatively, write in B1:B3 of sheet 1: "prefix1", "prefix2", "prefix3" (without the quotes) and then do:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Sheet1!B:B&char(9)),3),char(9)))&transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Sheet1!A:A&char(9),3)),char(9))) )
```